# In MS Word, can you use advanced find to match formatted text copied to the clipboard?

Tags: microsoft-word, find, copy-paste, clipboard, text-formatting

I am aware that you can use `Advanced Find and Replace` -> `Format` to match entire strings formatted a certain way, e.g. as described [here](https://word.tips.net/T001817_Searching_for_Text_With_a_Certain_Format.html).

Is there any way to match more complex formatting copied to the clipboard?

In other words is there any way to copy from a Word document:

[image]

And then use Advanced Find to match, in another Word document:

[image]

but not:

[image]

If relevant, I'm using Word for Mac OS, 16.40.

Comment: Is the text in Ms Word or in the clipboard?

Comment: Ah, interesting question.  In this example, I'm copying from a PDF.  I don't know enough about how the clipboard works under the hood to know if it should matter or not.

Comment: The link shows how to find/search texts in MS Word not the clipboard. You tagged the question as microsoft-word, while your application is adobe-acrobat. Maybe you should change the tag.

Comment: I want to copy from a PDF and then find in Word.  I think the question is more Word than Adobe unless there is a difference between applications in how formatting is retained on the clipboard.

Comment: You can't search for text containing more than one format.

Comment: This is essentially pasted text or a pdf conversion. A lot is going to depend on how the text gets into Word and what you end up with. It is possible, although not  likely, that you end up with a picture of text inside a Word document that looks like it is text.

Comment: The PDF aspect of this question is too much of a distraction so I am editing to be a Word to Word question.  Thank you for helping me narrow the question.

Comment: @harrymc if you feel like putting this into an answer, I will accept.  You look like you're probably an authority on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you are looking to search for an exact string
that contains more than one format. In the example we find normal-style
characters mixed with italic-style characters.

Unfortunately, Word can only search for text that is mono-format.
That's the only option that is possible using the Word Find dialog.

Comment: Know any word processing software that *can* do this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. You might need a specialized document management software.

Comment: Asked follow up question here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/79613/word-processing-software-or-other-text-based-tool-that-can-find-text-with-comp